# Merge two images into one and overflow hidden with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two images in different div's. Like this for Now:

I wanted to know if the top image can be merge in the background image if it goes out of the position of background image. It should have to show only in the area of background image. and when it goes out or if it is out of its border it should have to be overflow hidden like.

Comment: Hi Hassan, we would love to assist you but your description is a little unclear as to what you want to achieve. Please post the code you have tried so far and perhaps mock up a visual of the end result you want using any photo editor or wireframing tool so we know what the end result should look like. Without this, your question is likely to be flagged or removed for lack of clarity.

Comment: http://creativedesignmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/best-photoshop-tutorials7.jpg

Lets suppose in on div i have an png image space ship and into other is background if the spaceship position is in the middle of any area of background it have to be visible but if it is half out of background it should have to display half whats in and half disappear whats out of background. And if its totally out of background it should have to be disappear all.

Comment: Place the "ship" PNG as a child of the boundary container - set the boundary container to overflow:hidden, and move the ship around in the boundary container as needed. Any time that the "ship" png moves beyond the edge of the boundary container it will be automatically clipped for you.

Comment: @Korgrue can you give me some code like how to set the child of boundary?

Comment: Added code sample in answer below for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the "ship" PNG as a child of the boundary container - set the boundary container to overflow:hidden, and move the ship around in the boundary container as needed. Any time that the "ship" png moves beyond the edge of the boundary container it will be automatically clipped for you.

Technically you don't need the child div, you can just place the image inside the parent div - but putting the image in a child div will give you more control over the image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"><img src="path-to-your-image/ship.png" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: But I want the border to border like png is different not square in shape and it overflow on whole div i just to apply on image png overflow hidden or with javascript. I know overflow:hidden is for hidden but it doesn't work on png.

Comment: Make sure your png has a transparent background (so you don't have a white box behind it). Overflow hidden will work on any div - regardless of content within in. It is a fundamental part of the CSS spec. Any part of the PNG that you move outside of the parent div will be clipped. If this is not happening - then add overflow:hidden to the child as well (you should not have to do this if your browser is implementing the spec properly).